# How to efficiently perform a grid search for a large matrix in Python?

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, numpy, matrix

Given a nxn matrix A (it's actually an adjacency matrix for a graph), I need look all possible mxm submatrices (m =8 in this case) of that matrix, and pass the submatrix to a function and collect its result.

Right now, I am doing this as follows:

```
# generate all possible 8x8 submatrices 
for w in itertools.combinations(range(n), m):
         # extract 8x8 submatrix from the matrix
         submatrix = A[np.ix_(list(w),list(w))]
         # do some work on the submatrix
         foo(submatrix)
```

The problem is: the code above works well up to n=30x30 matrix (there are about 5 million possible m=8x8 submatrices to search for). However, I would like to apply my algorithm to up to n=100x100 matrices, which means (100 choose 8) = 186 billion possible submatrices.

Is there anything that I can do this process faster? Or is it hopelessly difficult problem to tackle?

Comment: For "do this process faster", are you looking to vectorize this, or are you looking for a solution that avoids looking at 186 billion windows? If you need the second thing, we'll need more details.

Comment: Come to think of it, this doesn't really sound like an MxM window. Isn't a window usually contiguous?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to analyze all size 8 subgraphs of your graph. In that case, you can't use a contiguous window. Depending on your task, you may be able to apply graph theory to reduce the amount of work to be done, or maybe just rent more computers.

Comment: Yes, this is hopelessly difficult. What does foo compute, and what do you actually want to know about your graph? Thinking about this question might help you along, but even then there is a good chance you are in trouble. Many graph problems in graph theory simply are very hard.

Comment: You need to seriously ask yourself whether you always need all 8 - using dynamic programming you may be able to re-use the result of the first m of n; this will speed up the over all processing speed dramatically. This is a case where you need to work smarter, not harder - or you will get nowhere.

Comment: Yes, I actually realized that instead of the whole matrix, I can just look at upper half (since this is an adj. matrix, it is symmetric). Hopefully, this will reduce the cost a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import generic_filter

m = np.arange(100*100).reshape((100,100))

def myfunction(data):
    mean = np.mean(data)
    return mean 

%timeit results = generic_filter(m, myfunction, size=8)
#10 loops, best of 3: 96.6 ms per loop
```

Solution using the [generic_filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter.html) of scipy.ndimage

Comment: The OP seems to be using a strange definition of window, so it's not clear whether this actually does what the OP wants.

Comment: ahh, yeah reread the question now. This is probably not what he want.

Comment: I edited the question. The "window" in my case is actually a submatrix. I am working on an adjacency matrix and trying to find all possible submatrices that can exist within that large matrix. Unfortunately, putting a contiguous window doesn't do what i want.